# How to give a variable a default value if no argument is supplied to the constructor? C++

Tags: c++, constructor, arguments, default

How do I make it so a default value is given to a variable if no argument is supplied to the constructor?

For example:

```
class A { 

A(int x, int y)

}

int main() { 
 A(4);
}
```

In that example I have not passed a value to y, how would I make it so y has a default value of 0 for example because no arguments where supplied?

Answer (score 4):

Use default arguments, with the restriction that parameters can only have default values reading from right to left, so defaulting `x` without defaulting `y` is not an option:

```
A(int x, int y = 0) {}
```

Your other choice is to make an overload:

```
A(int x, int y) {}
A(int x) {/*use 0 instead of y*/}
```

The second can work particularly well with delegating constructors for more complex combinations:

```
A(int x, int y) {/*do main work*/}
A(int x) : A(x, 0) {/*this is run after the other constructor*/}
```

As soon as you do any of these, though, be aware that implicit conversions to your class are easier. Instead of the only possible `{6, 10}`, you've gained the possibility of passing `5` as an `A`. Think hard before allowing these implicit conversions, and until you know you want them, stick `explicit` in front of the constructor signature to disable them.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, It depends on whether the implicit conversion is desirable or not. In most cases, it's a good idea to put in the `explicit`, though, and when it doubt, it's always easier to remove later than add later.

Comment: I was just thinking it would be a nice addition to the answer ;)

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, I guess I can add a tidbit on it in there :p

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass a default value to a parameter you can specify it in the constructor declaration.

```
class A
{ 
    A(int x, int y = 0)
    {
    }
};

int main()
{ 
    A(4);
}
```

Be careful when declaring default arguments for a constructor. Any constructor that can be called with a single argument can invoke an implicit conversion if it is not declared `explicit`.

```
A(int x = 0, int y = 0) // <-- can invoke implicit conversion
A(int x, int y = 0)     // <-- can invoke implicit conversion
A(int x, int y)         // <-- does NOT implicit conversion
```

To prevent implicit conversions from occuring declare the constructor as `explicit`

```
explicit A(int x = 0, int y = 0) // <-- No longer invokes implicit conversion
explicit A(int x, int y = 0)     // <-- No longer invokes conversion
A(int x, int y)                  // <-- does not require explicit keyword
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give default variable so the constructor becomes

```
A(int x=5, int y=4)

}
```

The default value of y becomes 4  and x has default of 5